# Should I put a "technician" pseudo-internship on my resume for biology grad school?

Tags: graduate-admissions, cv, biology

I completed a pseudo-internship-like experience offered by one of my undergraduate professors this semester. The job title was "biology technician," but my jobs were more geared towards learning than actual work.

Tasks I learned were: cleaning glassware in the biology department, organizing microscopes slides, cleaning microscopes, calibrating digital pipettes, and basic autoclave operations.

There were many other tasks, but I fail to remember them now, but **would these skills be a boon to a grad school application, and if so, how would I incorporate them into a 1 page resume?** I even filmed a video on autoclave use for instructional purpose.

Comment: How much else do you have to put in the resume?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan    Not much, my grades are not stellar, 3.0ish GPA from a State liberal arts school. 1 or 2 research projects in the work. And a potential volunteer position at the local hospital getting water and pillows. I still have 1 year of school left though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, why not? For a grad school application, you might as well list anything that shows your interest   and involvement in your field. List it as whatever your job title was, and if possible add a line or two describing your activities.

But if possible you will want to inform them about it in more depth. If the application includes a cover letter, statement of purpose, or similar essay, use it to describe what you did in this internship and what you learned. If the application requires recommendation letters, consider asking the professor who supervised your internship to write one.